# Firebase deployed to wrong hosting when multiple projects used

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting, firebase-cli

I have two firebase projects: `myapp` for prod, and `myapp-dev` for dev environment.
I first used the firebase cli to init my project with "myapp" and so all the files were generated with this, including the hosting resource `myapp` (so I can deploy my app to `myapp.web.app`).

Then I have added a second firebase project ("myapp-dev"). I run those

```
firebase use --add myapp-dev  # I have selected the right myapp-dev firebase project and set `dev` as short name
firebase target:apply hosting myapp-dev myapp  # note here that I also use name "myapp" as resource
```

I have manually changed my `.firebasesrc` because I want the dev project to be default...

So my `.firebasesrc` looks like this

```
{
  "projects": {
    "default": "myapp-dev",
    "prod": "myapp"
  },
  "targets": {
    "myapp": {
      "hosting": {
        "myapp": [
          "myapp"
        ]
      }
    },
    "myapp-dev": {
      "hosting": {
        "myapp": [
          "myapp"
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

and `firebase.json`

```
{
  "hosting": [
    {
      "target": "myapp",
      "public": "public",
      "ignore": [
        "firebase.json",
        "**/.*",
        "**/node_modules/**"
      ],
      "rewrites": [
        {
          "source": "**",
          "destination": "/index.html"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "functions": {
    "predeploy": [
      "npm --prefix \"$RESOURCE_DIR\" run lint"
    ]
  }
}
```

Now when I ran those lines, the webapp got deployed to the prod env, the `functions` to the dev env...

```
firebase use myapp-dev
firebase deploy
```

### EDIT

Running `firebase target:apply hosting myapp myapp-dev` helped !

Answer (score 3):

In my case I had the same app deploying to 2 different environments (development and production). The documentation is not very clear on this scenario, took some playing around to get the right config.

.firebaserc

```
{
  "projects": {
    "production": "myapp-prod",
    "development": "myapp-dev"
  },
  "targets": {
    "myapp-prod": {
      "hosting": {
        "myapp": [
          "site-name-prod"
        ]
      }
    },
    "myapp-dev": {
      "hosting": {
        "myapp": [
          "site-name-dev"
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

firebase.json

```
{
  "hosting": [{
    "target": "myapp",
    "public": "dist",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "rewrites": [ {
      "source": "**",
      "destination": "/index.html"
    } ]
  }]
}
```

To deploy to production run

```
firebase use production
firebase deploy
```

To deploy to development

```
firebase use development
firebase deploy
```

When you run firebase deploy in the project, it uses the target specified in the hosting section on the firebase.json to deploy to the site name specified in the hosting section of the target in the .firebaserc

Answer (score 0):

I think your config should be something like this.

file `.firebasesrc`

```
  "targets": {
    "myapp-dev": {
      "hosting": {
        "myapp-dev": [
          "myapp-dev"
        ],
        "myapp": [
          "myapp"
        ]
      }
    }
  }
```

file `firebase.json:`

```
  "hosting": [
    {
      "target": "myapp-dev",
      "public": "build",
      "ignore": [
        "firebase.json",
        "**/.*",
        "**/node_modules/**"
      ],
      "rewrites": [
        {
          "source": "**",
          "destination": "/index.html"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "target": "myapp",
      "public": "dist/myapp", /* folder */
      "ignore": [
        "firebase.json",
        "**/.*",
        "**/node_modules/**"
      ],
      "rewrites": [
        {
          "source": "**",
          "destination": "/index.html"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
```

and then deploy using `target` [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli/targets)